# I want to print out a list from a JSON data with a key as a list header in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{
  "error": [{
      "domain": "(SA 1) ",
      "LessonName": "SA 1 Unit 1",
    }, {
      "domain": " (SA 1)",
      "LessonName": "SA 1 Unit 2",
    }, {
      "domain": " (SA 1) ",
      "LessonName": "SA 1 Unit 3",
    }, {
      "domain": "(SA 2) ",
      "LessonName": "SA 2 Unit 1",
    }, {
      "domain": "(SA 2) ",
      "LessonName": "SA 2 Unit 2",
    }, {
      "domain": "(SA 2) ",
      "LessonName": "SA 2 Unit 3",
    }, {
      "domain": "(PSLT) ",
      "LessonName": "PSLT 1",
    }, {
      "domain": "(PSIT) ",
      "LessonName": "PSIT 1",
    },

  ]
}
```

Above is the structure of the JSON object I am working with.

I want to print out a sorted list that look like this in jquery can anyone help

```
> SA 1(domain)
>  SA 1 Unit 1(lessons under domain)
>  SA 1 Unit 2
>  SA 1 Unit 3
> SA 2(domain)
>  SA 2 Unit 1(lessons under domain)
>  SA 2 Unit 2
>  SA 2 Unit 3
> PSLT(domain)
>  PSIT 1(lessons under domain)
```

This is the code I am using below. But it is unable to print all the domain headers

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: elaurl,
  type: 'GET',
  error: function(jqXHR, text_status, strError) {
    alert("no connection");
  },
  timeout: 60000,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.error.length);
    json = response;
    var temp = '';
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;

    //  var data = "'<h4>'" + response.error[i].domain + "'<h4/>'";

    for (i = 0; i < response.error.length; i++) {

      if (response.error[i].domain != response.error[i + 1].domain) {

        var data = '<h4>' + response.error[i + 1].domain + '<h4/>';

        $('#domain').append(data);
        i++;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far? Normally SO questions include a code sample and an error message. People generally don't create solutions from scratch as answers :-)

Comment: Yes I have , but it doesnt work as I want. I have added the coded I am working with @ ADyson

Answer (score 0):

You know that you're always going to print out the "lesson" element of each item in the list, and you only want to print out the "domain" element if it's different than the one before it, yes?

Your AJAX response function might look similar to this:

```
success: function(response) {
   var $html = $('#domain');
   response.error.forEach(function(e, i) {
     // only print the domain if it's different than the previous error
     if (i===0 || e.domain !== response.error[i-1].domain) {
       $('<h4/>').text(e.domain).appendTo($html);
     }

     // always print the lesson
     $('<h5/>').text(e.lesson).appendTo($html);
   });
}
```

Comment: @ Briley Hooper , I tried it and it worked , very simple and straight forward

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

1) Data quality. Your JSON is not consistent - e.g your domain SA 1 is actually represented in 3 different ways in your sample, as "(SA 1) ", " (SA 1)" and " (SA 1) ". This will cause any string comparisons between them to fail because they'll never match each other.

2) The code isn't quite right. You're never even attempting to print the lesson name, and there's a logic error in the loop where you increment `i` an extra time for no reason, meaning you miss out some of the rows.

Here's the corrected data and code:

**JSON**

```
{
  "error": [{
    "domain": "(SA 1)",
    "LessonName": "SA 1 Unit 1",
  }, {
    "domain": "(SA 1)",
    "LessonName": "SA 1 Unit 2",
  }, {
    "domain": "(SA 1)",
    "LessonName": "SA 1 Unit 3",
  }, {
    "domain": "(SA 2)",
    "LessonName": "SA 2 Unit 1",
  }, {
    "domain": "(SA 2)",
    "LessonName": "SA 2 Unit 2",
  }, {
    "domain": "(SA 2)",
    "LessonName": "SA 2 Unit 3",
  }, {
    "domain": "(PSLT)",
    "LessonName": "PSLT 1",
  }, {
    "domain": "(PSIT)",
    "LessonName": "PSIT 1",
  },
  ]
};
```

**Code**

```
success: function(response) {
  var currentDomain = "";
  var data = "";

  for (i = 0; i < response.error.length; i++) 
  {

    if (response.error[i].domain != currentDomain) 
    {
      data += '<h4>' + response.error[i].domain + '<h4/>';
      currentDomain = response.error[i].domain;
    }
    data += "Lesson: " + response.error[i].LessonName + '<br/>';
  }
  $('#domain').append(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps. Before even attempting to put your structure into an HTML list, you need to group it properly, otherwise things get pretty hairy and prone to error.

Read and play with the code below. It outputs an array with the hierarchy you need to then create your HTML.

```js
var response = {
    "error": [
        {
            "domain": "(SA 1) ",
            "LessonName": "SA 1 Unit 1",
        }, {
            "domain": " (SA 1)",
            "LessonName": "SA 1 Unit 2",
        }, {
            "domain": " (SA 1) ",
            "LessonName": "SA 1 Unit 3",
        }, {
            "domain": "(SA 2) ",
            "LessonName": "SA 2 Unit 1",
        }, {
            "domain": "(SA 2) ",
            "LessonName": "SA 2 Unit 2",
        }, {
            "domain": "(SA 2) ",
            "LessonName": "SA 2 Unit 3",
        }, {
            "domain": "(PSLT) ",
            "LessonName": "PSLT 1",
        }, {
            "domain": "(PSIT) ",
            "LessonName": "PSIT 1",
        },
    ]
};

function success(response) {
    var currentDomain = '';
    // First make your group headers
    var redux = response.error
    // Get the headers first
    .reduce(function(acc, errorObj) {
        var cleanDomain = errorObj.domain.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
        if (cleanDomain !== currentDomain) {
            acc.push({ domain: cleanDomain, children: [] });
            currentDomain = cleanDomain;
        }
        return acc;
    }, [])
    // For each header, add children
    .map(function (domainObj) {
        // From all errors get the corresponding ones for lesson name, and take the title only
        var firstLessonFound = false;
        domainObj.children = response.error.reduce(function (acc, item) {
            if (item.domain.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '') === domainObj.domain) {
                var string = item.LessonName;
                if (!firstLessonFound) {
                    string += ' (blah)';
                    firstLessonFound = true;
                }
                acc.push(string);
            }
            return acc;
        }, []);
        return domainObj;
    });

    console.log(redux)
    // Here you then iterate over redux and generate your HTML
}

success(response);
```